# Display table from SQL table in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch-api

I have been trying to set up backend of a website, but I have issue when trying to read it on frontend where I am using React.

**Setup**:

- I have a table of products which contain properties (name, price, isBestSeller, isAvailable etc).
- I am reading this table and sending data to frontend with NodeJS as shown in the code below:

`

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const fs = require('fs');
const knex = require('knex')
const database = knex({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      host : '127.0.0.1',
      user : 'username',
      password : '',
      database : 'databasename'
    }
  });
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
database.select('*').from('products').then(data => {
    app.get('/', (req, res) => { 
        res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
});
app.listen(3001);
```

`

This works fine and if I console.log it I get the proper data.
Issue appears in frontend as I am not yet that familiar with fetch and promises.

Before I introduced backend I was reading products from a simple .js file which contained array of objects like this:

```
export const productsContent = [
  {
    boxImage: 'https://i.imgur.com/dn9ty6l.png', 
    boxTitle: 'Arabusta Arabica', 
    boxPrice: '€15', 
    discountPrice: '€9.99',
    bestSeller: false,
    available: false,
    description: 'Coming soon'
  },
   ...
]
```

Now I replaced above code with this:

```
export const productsContent = [
  fetch('http://localhost:3001')
  .then(function(response) { return response.json(); })
  .then(function(data) { 
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      productsContentArray.push(data);

    }
  })
];
```

What I am attempting to do here is fetch array of objects from backend and push it to constant productsContent and use it to display products.

Unfortunately, outside of `.fetch` I get promise which I am not sure how to parse and when I console inside of fetch I get proper values.

Does anyone know how can I properly resolve promise from fetch or how to get value from data outside of fetch function?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're on the right track, but try moving your fetch logic outside of the array, something like this alternative solution:

```
const Products = {
     getContent() {
        return fetch(`http://localhost:3001/`, {
            headers: {
                // header info here
                // e.g. 
                // "Content-type": "application/json",
            }
        }).then(res => {
            return res.json();
        }).then(jsonResponse => {
            return jsonResponse;
        });
    }
}

export default Products;
```

Then, within your front-end, you can do something like the following:

```
// other imports
import Products from "./Products";

// do other things

const getProductResponse = Products.getContent();
// handle productResponse status code
console.log(getProductResponse);
// do things with your data
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `Products.getContent()` still returns the _Promise_ like my code does.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the [i] part in the push(data) on line 6 was missing

```
1| export const productsContent = [
2|   fetch('http://localhost:3001')
3|   .then(function(response) { return response.json(); })
4|   .then(function(data) { 
5|     for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
6|       productsContentArray.push(data[i]);
7|     }
8|   })
9| ];
```